# Ionic 3 grid size won't adapt to smaller screen

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an Ionic 3 mobile app that I have developed, where I have form fields that I setup in a grid.

There are 3 columns that should appear side-by-side.

In most models it looks fine, but when I view it on an iPhone 5s or even on 6s, the fields do not appear side-by-side.

Instead, the input field drops a line and fills out 100% of the width, with the other columns at the top.

Here is my code:

```
<ion-grid fixed *ngIf="showPhone">
  <ion-row class="edit-field">
    <ion-col col-auto class="field-icon">
      <ion-icon name="md-remove-circle"></ion-icon>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-auto class="field-type">
      <select name="phoneType" [(ngModel)]="phoneData.phone_type">
        <option value="select"> -- Select -- </option>
        <option value="home">home</option>
        <option value="mobile">mobile</option>
        <option value="business">business</option>
        <option value="home fax">home fax</option>
        <option value="work fax">work fax</option>
        <option value="fax">fax</option>
      </select>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col class="field-input">
      <input type="text" 
      [(ngModel)]="phoneData.phone_number" 
      (blur)="addPhone(phoneData)"
      placeholder="Phone">
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Howe can I make it so that it adapts when viewed on a smaller screen?

Comment: I have never been to this situation. but I belive grid breakpoints could solve this, by adding col-sm-.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries for fix it. Depending on the screen size you need to change the width.

ex:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
 }

 /* On screens that are 600px or less, set the background color to olive */
 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: olive;
  }
 //whatever in CSS.
 }
```

If you Need to affect the CSS code only for IOS, You should check the platform in css.

Any queries please refer the link https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-specific-styles/